# TLS 1.3 - GREASE - What if Middleboxes are updated to simply ignore GREASE values? Doesn't the problem GREASE is trying to fix still exist?

Tags: tls

Various ambiguous "middleboxes" exist at arbitrary points throughout the Internet between a Client and Server's TLS connection.

A possible intent of these middleboxes is to enforce protocol standards, which sounds great in theory but hinders quick adoption when updating to new versions of a protocol -- as is what happened during the migration to TLS 1.3 from TLS 1.2 and prior.

A solution (well, deterrent) to this happening again in the future is the **GREASE** protocol specified by [RFC 8701](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8701.html) (Applying **G**enerate **R**andom **E**xtensions **A**nd **S**ustain **E**xtensibility TLS Extensibility).

The crux of how it works is in places where new features/constructs *could* be added (TLS Extensions, TLS Versions, TLS Ciphers, etc...) have TLS Clients occasionally send random values *specified by the GREASE rfc* to prompt these middlebox errors more often and bring more attention to fixing them, or even discourage the behavior of dropping packets when unknown values are seen.

My question is about the italic portion above... **since the GREASE RFC [explicitly lists and reserves the set of GREASE values](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8701.html#name-grease-values), middleboxes could be updated to ignore *those* values, but continue to drop *other* unknown values** -- effectively putting us back to the initial problem that GREASE was meant to fix.

If GREASE picked values to use at random, but didn't limit the values to a pre-defined list, I could see how it would discourage the middleboxes of the future from dropping packets when seeing unknown values, since they would be "see unknown values" all the time.

But since the "unknown values" are actually *known* and *specified* in the RFC... I can't help but think we're just repeating scenario which caused the initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Various ambiguous "middleboxes" exist at arbitrary points throughout the Internet between a Client and Server's TLS connection.

I'm assuming that you are referring to SSL intercepting proxies in companies and SSL terminating load balancers here.

> A possible intent of these middleboxes is to enforce protocol standards, which sounds great in theory but hinders quick adoption when updating to new versions of a protocol -- as is what happened during the migration to TLS 1.3 from TLS 1.2 and prior.

If the intent was to enforce protocol standards, then this intend failed due to non-conformance of these boxes to protocol standards, i.e. the very point GREASE is trying to early detect. The extensibility with new ciphers, signature algorithms, protocol versions and extensions are part of the TLS protocol already and failing to handle this gracefully means not following the protocol standards.

Note that such SSL intercepting middleboxes are the endpoints of the TLS connection. Thus they don't need to enforce specific protocols apart from maybe enforcing minimal security requirements for protocol version or cipher strength. Anything which they don't understand could be simply ignored, as defined by the TLS standard.

In reality these problems are typically not caused by the intend to enforce a standard, but by making assumptions on how the standards are used and by making implementation shortcuts and performance optimizations which are possible within these assumptions. In practice this resulted in making [wrong assumptions about the size of the ClientHello](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K14758) or the [inability to simply ignore unsupported TLS extensions](https://www.mail-archive.com/postfix-users@postfix.org/msg57455.html).

> ... middleboxes could be updated to ignore those values, but continue to drop other unknown values -- effectively putting us back to the initial problem that GREASE was meant to fix.

In theory this could be done. In practice though this not only means to neglect the extensibility of TLS as done before, but to explicitly deny extensibility. These middleboxes are not primarily there to prevent connectivity though, but to control connectivity and at the end allow most of it. Thus being aware of the extensibility and explicitly denying it is not in the interest of the users and customers of such middleboxes and will result in costly support and bugfixes. Therefore it is less likely that vendors will simply work around GREASE, but more likely that GREASE will early detect wrong assumptions - i.e. what it was intended for.

Answer (score 1):

These "middleboxes" are called "routers" and are not involved in TLS connections. Their task is to route packets from one net to the other, so that the destination server can receive them and build connections. Alternatively, the TLS connection could terminate at a load balancer, in which case the load balancer becomes the server.

> What prevents a server from just ignoring GREASE and dropping connections on real unknown exensions?

Nothing. It's just a really bad way to behave. It's kind of a "worst of both world" situation. The reason GREASE exists, as you state in your question, is to have a known way of finding potentially hard-to-diagnose problems. So it's a good idea to make use of it.

> Why wouldn't GREASE just pick random values?

Because that could interfere with future TLS extensions. Imagine some future extension uses the ID `0xCAFE` to identify itself, signalling that the client supports the CAFE extension. If GREASE were to use 0xCAFE randomly, then GREASE stops being a tool to test how endpoints react to **unknown** extensions, and instead becomes a fuzz testing tool how endpoints react to any kind of arbitrary input on **known** extensions as well.

This is undesirable, so listing and reserving a set of GREASE extensions and demanding that these **MUST NOT** be treated any differently from unknown extensions, is the best course of action to take here.

> Aren't we just repeating the same mistakes?

No, the initial mistake was to believe clients will always send extensions known to the endpoint. GREASE is supposed to fix that, by causing clients to randomly send "unknown" extensions.

This already caused lots of bugs to be fixed, which is good for everyone. Treating GREASE extensions in a special way means opting out of free bug testing, which is not in any way desirable.

Comment: Humbly, I disagree... the middleboxes are much more than simply Routers. There are a slew of Firewalls and IPS and even IDSs that do protocol enforcement. Infact, if a Router is hindering things as a "middlebox" is described above, I would argue the Router is acting like *more than a Router* ... the router would then be acting like some sort of FW/IDS/IPS, etc.

Comment: As for the `0xCAFE` example, if a Client sends CAFE extension, and the server supports the CAFE feature, the server will respond with whatever is necessary for CAFE to work. If the server doesn't support it, it will ignore it.  Whether the server *understands* CAFE and isn't supporting the feature, or *doesn't understand* CAFE, the respond is and should be the same:  silently ignore it.  The Client can then choose to continue the connection, or terminate if CAFE is critical.  Given all that, I don't see how GREASE sending `0xCAFE` before it exists as an established extension hurts anything.

Comment: The problem arises if the client sends 0xCAFE as grease value, because it doesn't know there is a "CAFE" extension. The server receives the supposed GREASE value and concludes: Oh, nice, the client already supports the CAFE extension. Let's continue with an optimized handshake scheme that's incompatible with pre-CAFE clients. The client then receives a reply it can't understand because the server mistreated the GREASE value as real extension.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Good point!  I hadn't thought of the case where the client sends the extension code as a GREASE extension, but the server understands it as a non-GREASE code.  Thank you.

Comment: @Eddie Sorry, I feel like I should have explained that better in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> middleboxes could be updated to ignore those values, but continue to drop other unknown values

That's perfectly fine. They can drop whatever VALUES they want, as long as the CONNECTION remains alive.

The [ChromeStatus page for GREASE](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6475903378915328) (archived [here](https://archive.ph/wip/EOUhu)) has a very short and good explanation of the whole point of GREASE:

> TLS clients offer lists of 16-bit code points (e.g. cipher suites) that servers select from. To remain extensible, servers must ignore unknown values. However, servers may have bugs and reject unknown values. These servers will interoperate with existing clients, so the mistake may spread unnoticed, breaking extensibility for the whole ecosystem. We will reserve some values to advertise at random, to prevent such mistakes before broken servers are widespread.